# How to track from which page request is redirected in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have three pages calculator1.aspx, calculator2.aspx and Menu.aspx. 
On each calculator page i have a button that redirect me to Menu page and on Menu page i have to go back to Calculator1 or calculator2 page from where the request initiated. So how can i differentiate from which page my request come when im on Menu page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best bet it to check the [`HTTP_REFERER`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) header. It can be spoofed, but more often than not it will be enough.

```
string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of URL rewriting.
on click of button on calulator1.aspx write

```
Response.Redirect('menu.aspx?page=cal1')
```

on click of button on calulator2.aspx write

```
Response.Redirect('menu.aspx?page=cal2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Page.PreviousPage` property, to get the page that transferred control to the current page.
Or using `HttpRequest.UrlReferrer` property, to get information about the URL of the client's previous request that linked to the current URL.

**[Links]**
[Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)
[HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)